# installing svn connectors in eclipse luna's "dropins" folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to automate installation of the SVN connector plugins required by subversive in Eclipse Luna for a shared multi-user installation.  I've downloaded the plugins by running eclipse as a limited user, and then I copied the files from that user's private "features" and "plugins" directories to the eclipse installation's "dropins" directory (in my case, making directories `/opt/eclipse-4.4RC2/dropins/features` and `/opt/eclipse-4.4RC2/dropins/plugins` and putting them in those).  However, when I start eclipse now, the connectors are not available in the drop down list of connectors in Window/Preferences/Team/SVN/SVN Connector, and I get the following messages in my error log:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse
Error
Mon Jun 02 03:52:28 UTC 2014
Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /opt/eclipse-4.4RC2/dropins/plugins.

org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse
Error
Mon Jun 02 03:52:28 UTC 2014
Unable to acquire PluginConverter service during generation for: /opt/eclipse-4.4RC2/dropins/features.
```

I'm aware that the PluginConverter has been removed from Luna; it previously provided backwards compatibility with Eclipse 2.0 plugins that lack OSGi manifests, but all the plugins I've attempted to install have correct OSGi manifests, so I don't understand why it would be required.

I've tried to check with Luna's documentation that creating `features` and `plugins` as subdirectories of `dropins` should work, but cannot find any documentation for Luna (a little odd as it's due for final release in only a couple of weeks, I thought).  Kepler's documentation suggests it should be fine, though.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Eclipse bug [426456](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426456).

The bug report says that restarting Eclipse **twice** with the `-clean` option worked around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to automate the installation of SVN connectors in Luna (directly in the plugins folder, using the polarion update site) :

```
${installationpath}/eclipse/eclipse -nosplash \
  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
  -repository http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/update-site/ \
  -destination ${installationpath}/eclipse/ \
  -installIU org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group \
  -installIU org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit18.feature.group
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to install subversive and its connector is as below:

```
1. Go to Help->Install New software.
2. From the drop down list select "Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna". Now some list should be populated.
3. In the populated list go to Collaborator->Subversive SVN Team Provider.
4. Click Finish.
```

This is will install Subversive SVN Team Provider after restart of eclipse.

Then right click on empty are of Project Explorer and select import and then other. From the new menu select SVN-Project from SVN , this will ask for connector installation. Select desired connector and install it.

HTH